# How to run NHibernate aggregate on a TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a table `Foo`:

```
create table Foo(
  FooId uniqueidentifier not null,
  UserId uniqueidentifier not null,
  TimeSpent bigint not null)
```

This is mapped to a class:

```
public class Foo
{
  public Guid FooId {get; set;}
  public Guid UserId {get; set;}
  public TimeSpan TimeSpent {get; set;}
}
```

And in the NHibernate `ClassMap<Foo>`:

```
Id(x => x.FooId).Not.Nullable().GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
Map(x => x.UserId).Not.Nullable();
Map(x => x.TimeSpent).Not.Nullable();
```

All good so far. Now I want to write a query to get an aggregate of `TimeSpent` per user. In an ideal world it would be:

```
return Session.Query<Foo>()
  .GroupBy(f => f.UserId)
  .Select(g => new { UserId = g.Key, TotalTimeSpent = g.Sum(f => f.TimeSpent) });
```

But there's no native support for summing `TimeSpan` values, so instead we could say:

```
TotalTimeSpent = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(g.Sum(f => f.TimeSpent.TotalMilliseconds))
```

But of course, NHibernate doesn't know what this `TotalMilliseconds` property is, because that's purely a C# construct.

What's the correct way to aggregate `TimeSpan` values in NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked out one possible solution myself:

Add a `long` field to the class:

```
public long TimeSpentTicks {get; set;}
```

Add the mapping:

```
Map(x => x.TimeSpentTicks).Column("TimeSpent").ReadOnly();
```

And do the aggregate like so:

```
var result = Session.Query<Foo>()
 .GroupBy(f => f.UserId)
 .Select(g => new { UserId = g.Key, TotalTicks = g.Sum(f => f.TimeSpentTicks) })
 .ToList() // so we can convert to TimeSpan in managed code
 .Select(x => new { x.UserId, TotalTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(x.TotalTicks) });
```